# Xamarin Android FTP authentication problem on startup

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, ftps

I'm developing an Android application in C# language with Xamarin.
In this application I need a service that starts after the device boot and upload files in a FTP server.
If I start this service with a button click action all works good, but if I use a BroadcastReceiver and I intercept the BOOT_COMPLETED event to start the FTP connection, I receive this error:

```
ex.Message: The authentication or decryption has failed.
ex.StackTrace: at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult)
               at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream ()
               at TestProject.FTPUtility.upload (System.String userName, System.String password, System.String sourceFile, System.String targetFile)
```

I don't understand why I receive the authentication or decryption error only if the service starts on startup. I tried also to start the connection only after a ping success (to wait the device internet connection) but nothing is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with this line of code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

Comment: I must wait 2 days